# Find an inner product of $V =\mathbb{R_1[X]}$ with given basis

Tags: linear-algebra

$V =\mathbb{R_1[X]}$

Find an inner product such that $\{ 1+2x,2+5x\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$

I don't know how to approach this problem.

I found this [Find an Inner Product of two polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005735/find-an-inner-product-of-two-polynomials) but I don't get how to compute $<ax+b, cx+d>$.

Help is welcome , thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

First, write the polynomials as $\;2\,-$vectors (isomorphism $\;\Bbb R_1[x]\cong\Bbb R^2\;$) :

$$1+2x\to\binom12=:v_1\;,\;\;2+5x\to\binom25=:v_2$$

Let now $\;A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\;$ be positive definite ( i.e. $\; a>0\;,\;\;ad-bc>0\;$), so that $\;A\;$ defines an inner product on $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ as follows

$$x=\binom{x_1}{x_2}\;,\;\;y=\binom{y_1}{y_2}\in\Bbb R^2\implies \langle x, y\rangle:=x^tAy$$

Well, now check the conditions on $\;A\;$ so that you'll get

$$\langle v_i,v_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}\;\ldots$$

Comment: $\binom12^t\;\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\;\binom12=1$
and
$\binom25^t\;\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\;\binom25=1$
and
$\binom25^t\;\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\;\binom12=0$
 ?

Comment: In order to define an inner product, it's not enough that $A$ is positive definite. You need to ask $A$ to be symmetric.

Comment: @jjagmath That's already included in the definition of positive definite in most cases, or else it follows, as in the present real case, from the symmetry of the (real) inner product.